# What is a good framework for filemanagment combined with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

Here is the scenario:

A user visits the site ask the latest version of only one document. he or she changes something to that document (locally), the format is word, and then re-uploads that document to the website.

The uploading and downloading part is not that hard, but is there a framework that can for example analyse the differences from 2 documents (the one on the server vs. the one changed) and gives the user an option to merge (in case 2 people change the document and re-upload in different order)?

My first thought it would become a something that looks like dropbox or a subversion repository? is there a framework for this that you can use for an ASP.NET MVC website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the features you state, you're practically seeking a VCS. Your best bet is to go with SVN.

Install SVN server, download a .net wrapper such as [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) (developers of ankhSVN). Send your files to the svn server and use the api to manage them. (merge, query, etc)